# What do black dots represent on a combination logic circuit diagram?

Tags: logic, diagram

Hi everyone I am completing a truth table for the following combination logic diagram and I was wondering what the black dots on the diagram mean? I know the white circles found after the distinctive shape logic gates represent negations, however, I'm confused as to what the black dots mean. Also, I was wondering if those bumps found on the C path mean that any input that goes in to C will go directly to the logic gate found directly prior to the output. Thank you[image]

Answer (score 1):

The black dots stand for conjunction points. The bumps mean those two wires are not crossed with each other. In other words, the two inputs of the NOR gate(the gate at bottom) are A and B.

Comment: Thank you very much!